# Startup with more modules cause an error

Tags: jruby, vert.x

I have a really strange problem: I have two different selft written modules. When I run vertx with a single module no problem. When I run both I get a JSON uninitialized constant error with jruby.
But sometimes it work also with both modules. The modules has not been changed.
It was only new started
In the errorsection You can see two starts one working and one with an error.

Here is my app.coffee :

```
console=require("vertx/console")
container=require('vertx/container')
container.deployModule("io.vertx~mod-web-server~2.0.0-final",
console.log JSON.stringify(container.config)

{port:Number(container.config.port), 
host:container.config.host,
web_root: "public",
bridge: true,
prefix: "/eventbus",
inbound_permitted:[{"adress":"galleries"},
                     {"adress":"content"},
                     {"adress":"pdf_converter"}],

outbound_permitted:[{"adress":"pdf_show"},
                    {"adress":"send_to_browser_adress"}]
                  })

#Here the both modules
#Running both together does not work sometimes
#Running each other single works always

container.deployModule('org.kargers~gallery~0.0.1')     
container.deployModule('org.kargers~papierbrief~0.0.1')
```

Here ist works :

~/work/kargers.org/processing/vertx [1.7.2@masha_gems without_processing*] cd ~/work   /kargers.org/processing/vertx && rvm use jruby-1.7.2@masha_gems &vertx run ~/work/kargers.org/processing/vertx/server_app.js -conf dev.json

Using /home/erhard/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2 with gemset masha_gems
{"port":"8080","host":"localhost"}
galleries module loaded
converter module loaded

Here there is the problem :
(only restarted...)

~/work/kargers.org/processing/vertx [1.7.2@masha_gems without_processing*] cd ~/work/kargers.org/processing/vertx && rvm use jruby-1.7.2@masha_gems &vertx run ~/work/kargers.org/processing/vertx/server_app.js -conf dev.json
Using /home/erhard/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2 with gemset masha_gems
{"port":"8080","host":"localhost"}
Exception in JavaScript verticle
    org.vertx.java.core.VertxException: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (NameError) uninitialized constant JSON::Ext::Generator
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.JRubyVerticleFactory$JRubyVerticle.start(JRubyVerticleFactory.java:174)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.Verticle.start(Verticle.java:82)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$18.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1278)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:170)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:354)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(Nio

Comment: When I load a single module, no matter which one it works. vertx version 2.1 RC3. I deinstall also rvm to ensure to use the buildin jruby of sys-mod. Changing the sequence of modules : sometimes it happens with the first somtimes with the second module Is there any example for more than one ruby module out there ?

Comment: Now I brougth it to the point : I have 2 modules only the require "vertx" and a app.js which loads this modules than I get this error.